# Camera's position not changing when added to a mesh

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I want to realise a little TPS (the camera follow the player). I add the camera to a cube ( wich represents the players when he moves), and show the coordinates of the camera and the cube in : [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvbg2wuk/2/light/). The Camera is following the cube as well, but you can see that the camera coordinates are not changing. There is no problems but when i want to use the picking, the coordinates are wrong because it depends on the camera.

I just do that :

```
cube.add(Camera);
```

Somebody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the camera to the cube, you make it a `child` object. The coordinates of a child are `local coordinates` *relative to their parent* (as are the scale and rotation), so they do not change when the parent (the cube) moves.

What you want to know are the `world coordinates` of the camera. There is no direct property for those as Three.js only stores the complete world *matrix*, but it *does* offer a nice helper function to extract it from that matrix:

```
var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
cameraPosition.setFromMatrixPosition(Camera.matrixWorld);
```